# Can't you specify a date range when searching the repository corresponding to topic using github api?

Tags: github, github-api

You are going to search for a repository with registered topic using github api.

However, since the search results are limited to 1000, I would like to search the date as a limit. Like below.

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=topic:AAA&createdat:2020-10-11

Is there any other way since I ignored the date and searched?

I'd like to ask for your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a few issues in your query :

- the correct search query term is `created` (not createdat)
- the search query parameters are delimited by spaces like this :

  ```
  topic:AAA created:2020-10-11
  ```

Your query would be : https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=topic:AAA%20created:2020-10-11

From the [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/searching-for-information-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax#query-for-dates) :

> You can search for dates that are earlier or later than another date,
> or that fall within a range of dates, by using >, >=, <, <=, and range
> queries. Date formatting must follow the ISO8601 standard, which is
> YYYY-MM-DD (year-month-day).

A few examples:

- created after date:

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=topic:AAA%20created:%3E2017-10-11

- created between date:

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=topic:AAA%20created:2017-01-01..2018-01-01

Comment: how to search by last update time?

Comment: @CSQGB use `updated` instead of `created`